# What LEGO set are these bags from?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I've got tons of partially built sets. I don't know which set these bags belong to. Trying to sort my kids' LEGO bricks. Any tips welcome!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think you have bags from set [75876-1 Porsche 919 Hybrid and 917K Pit Lane](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75876-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) from the Speed Champions line of sets.

[image]

The Plate 4x4 Round Corner, in combination with the red and white color scheme, the tires and the transparent yellow 1x2 plates, as well as the fact that there are at least 6 bags (as per the numbers on the bags you have) drive me to this conclusion.

Comment: Agreed. The parts in each bag appear to match the parts in the instructions for this set: http://lego.brickinstructions.com/en/lego_instructions/set/75876/Porsche_919_Hybrid_and_917K_Pit_Lane